# Word means to make something better or worse?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sorry I'm not a English speaker.So my English maybe have some problem.
I want to ask if there's a word that means making something better or worse.
For example if you use this on a happy person,that means he become more happy.
But use on a sad person,it means he become more sad.

Comment: It sounds like you are *amplifying* or *intensifying* their mood.

Comment: There's a word for 'make better', _ameliorate_, but that is usually used for improving something that was not very good, like poor living conditions. You could speak of _increasing someone's happiness_.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***heighten***:

> - Make or become more intense.
>     *‘the pleasure was **heightened** by the sense of guilt that accompanied it’*
>
> <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/heighten)</sub>

An example for happiness:

> For example, someone who says they have a good sense of humor could try telling jokes to lighten up business meetings or cheer up sad friends. This habit, too, seems to ***heighten*** happiness.
> <sub>[Live Science](https://www.livescience.com/9824-5-happier.html)</sub>

An example for sadness:

> As women age, many go through the emotional process of a life review (measuring what they’ve done in their life as mortality approaches), which can ***heighten*** sadness.
> <sub>[Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/two-takes-depression/201309/late-in-life-suicide-concerning-trend?amp)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are **far too many** words in the English language that describe the dichotomous nature of both these moods to have a **single** word that describes the intensity of the feeling/s. Why would you want a single word when there are so many more that can exclusively express the happy/sad mood perspicuously.

Words like **alleviate**, **assuage**, **meliorate** essential have the crux as *reducing the intensity of a problem or reducing the intensity of pain to give relief*.

Words like **exacerbate** and **aggravate** mean *to make a problem worse*.

These words do not directly ascertain the mood of a person, but are definitely involved in the apprehending the person's mood.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/

Comment: What about *amplify* and *intensify* as suggested in the comments above? Happiness and sadness can both *increase*.

Comment: @nnnnnn I saw that. You cannot compare both these answers. Can you ascertain the difference in the perspective of the answers?